# Why should we implement form logic using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React brings increased rendering performance. A lot of the heavyweight contenders for MVVM frameworks have a hard time rendering large amounts of data, like in lists and such. React doesn’t have that problem, as it renders only what’s changed. So why should form be implemented using Reactjs?

Comment: What do you mean, why? I don't really understand your question?

Comment: Why would you implement some of your views with react, and some with something else? React is for any kind of UI - it is comfortable at doing forms too